# Raspberry Pi stuck in reboot loop, need to run a command

Tags: reboot, raspberry-pi, watchdog

Apparently I made a wrong configuration of the watchdog running on my Pi, which causes it to reboot in about 10 seconds after it boots up and shows the login script. Im not fast enough to run a command using a FTP client, so I need to run a command or delete a file elsehow. My Pi has the newest debian wheezy and I want to make it without having to delete all files.

EDIT:
I made it to fix the issue. Luckily it rebooted after 15 second, which was enough time to enter the SSH and delete the config in the very last second :D
I learned to always backup the system image now.

Comment: I recommend asking this at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not just pull out the card, mount it on your computer and delete the file? Assuming you have Linux, this is trivial.

Comment: if you dont have linux other than the raspi, then if you have a second sd card setup a new config on that second card boot that, put the problem card in a card reader and plug that into the raspberry pi and use that linux to find and replace or remove the problem file.